# Remove from the array elements that are repeated

Tags: ruby, arrays

What is the best way to remove from the array elements that are repeated.
For example, from the array

```
a = [4, 3, 3, 1, 6, 6]
```

need to get

```
a = [4, 1]
```

My method works to too slowly with big amount of elements.

```
arr = [4, 3, 3, 1, 6, 6]
puts arr.join(" ")
nouniq = []
l = arr.length
uniq = nil
for i in 0..(l-1)
  for j in 0..(l-1) 
    if (arr[j] == arr[i]) and ( i != j )
      nouniq << arr[j]
    end
  end
end
arr = (arr - nouniq).compact

puts arr.join(" ")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = [4, 3, 3, 1, 6, 6]
a.select{|b| a.count(b) == 1}
#=> [4, 1]
```

More complicated but faster solution (`O(n)` I believe :))

```
a = [4, 3, 3, 1, 6, 6]
ar = []
add = proc{|to, form| to << from[1] if form.uniq.size == from.size }
a.sort!.each_cons(3){|b| add.call(ar, b)}
ar << a[0] if a[0] != a[1]; ar << a[-1] if a[-1] != a[-2]
```

Comment: This works, but note that this is `O(n^2)`, i.e. very inefficient for large arrays (and same order that the OP's algorithm). See Jörg's answer for an efficient answer

Comment: but for small arrays it will be faster

Answer (score 4):

```
arr = [4, 3, 3, 1, 6, 6]

arr.
  group_by {|e| e }.
  map {|e, es| [e, es.length] }.
  reject {|e, count| count > 1 }.
  map(&:first)
# [4, 1]
```

Comment: @Joe: I'm still trying to figure out a better way. There *must* be a way using `inject`, since you can trivially prove that everything you can do with `each` can also be done with `inject` and all of the methods in `Enumerable` are based on `each`. Therefore everything you can do with *any* combination of `Enumerable` methods can also be done with `inject`. Whether that is more readable is another matter. I want to keep it down to an amortized worst-case step complexity of O(n), since @fl00r has already provided a much nicer O(n²) solution.

Comment: @Jörg can you give some links about O(n) and O(n²) in Ruby :)

Comment: @Jörg See my submission with inject

Comment: @fl00r: That notation is called *Bachmann-Landau notation*. The specific context I am using it in here is called *Algorithmic Complexity Theory*. There are plenty of questions about both subjects here on StackOverflow, although your best bet would probably be an algorithms and data structures textbook or course like [this lecture from MIT's 6.046J *Introduction to Algorithms* course](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-2-asymptotic-notation-recurrences-substitution-master-method/).

Comment: Would a C-implemented `count_by` method be faster (though still the same "big O") than a ruby-implemented `count_by.map` in YARV?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: Probably. What would be *really* interesting, though, is benchmarking that against Rubinius. Thanks to LLVM, they generate *crazy* fast machine code for straight-line Ruby code, and thanks to the dynamic optimizer and speculative inlining, they can optimize away a lot of method calls and thus produce large swaths of straight-line Ruby code for LLVM to chew on. E.g. the pure Ruby `Hash` class in Rubinius is faster than the hand-optimized C `Hash` in YARV. In other words, at least in this specific case, Ruby is faster than C.

Answer (score 2):

Without introducing the need for a separate copy of the original array and using inject:

```
[4, 3, 3, 1, 6, 6].inject({}) {|s,v| s[v] ? s.merge({v=>s[v]+1}) : s.merge({v=>1})}.select {|k,v| k if v==1}.keys
 => [4, 1]
```

Comment: [4, 3, 3, 1, 6, 6].inject({}) {|s,v| s.merge(s[v] ? {v=>s[v]+1} : {v=>1})}.select {|k,v| k if v==1}.keys

Answer (score 1):

I needed something like this, so tested a few different approaches. These all return an array of the items that are duplicated in the original array:

```
module Enumerable
def dups
  inject({}) {|h,v| h[v]=h[v].to_i+1; h}.reject{|k,v| v==1}.keys
end
def only_duplicates
  duplicates = []
  self.each {|each| duplicates << each if self.count(each) > 1}
  duplicates.uniq
end
def dups_ej
  inject(Hash.new(0)) {|h,v| h[v] += 1; h}.reject{|k,v| v==1}.keys
end
def dedup
  duplicates = self.dup
  self.uniq.each { |v| duplicates[self.index(v)] = nil }
  duplicates.compact.uniq
end
end
```

Benchark results for 100,000 iterations, first with an array of integers, then an array of strings. Performance will vary depending on the numer of duplicates found, but these tests are with a fixed number of duplicates (~ half array entries are duplicates):

```
test_benchmark_integer
                                    user     system      total        real
Enumerable.dups                 2.560000   0.040000   2.600000 (  2.596083)
Enumerable.only_duplicates      6.840000   0.020000   6.860000 (  6.879830)
Enumerable.dups_ej              2.300000   0.030000   2.330000 (  2.329113)
Enumerable.dedup                1.700000   0.020000   1.720000 (  1.724220)
test_benchmark_strings
                                    user     system      total        real
Enumerable.dups                 4.650000   0.030000   4.680000 (  4.722301)
Enumerable.only_duplicates     47.060000   0.150000  47.210000 ( 47.478509)
Enumerable.dups_ej              4.060000   0.030000   4.090000 (  4.123402)
Enumerable.dedup                3.290000   0.040000   3.330000 (  3.334401)
..
Finished in 73.190988 seconds.
```

So of these approaches, it seems the Enumerable.dedup algorithm is the best:

- dup the original array so it is immutable
- gets the uniq array elements
- for each unique element: nil the first occurence in the dup array
- compact the result

If only (array - array.uniq) worked correctly! (it doesn't - it removes everything)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my spin on a solution used by Perl programmers using a hash to accumulate counts for each element in the array:

```
ary = [4, 3, 3, 1, 6, 6]

ary.inject({}) { |h,a| 
  h[a] ||= 0
  h[a] += 1
  h 
}.select{ |k,v| v == 1 }.keys # => [4, 1]
```

It could be on one line, if that's at all important, by judicious use of semicolons between the lines in the `map`.

A little different way is:

```
ary.inject({}) { |h,a| h[a] ||= 0; h[a] += 1; h }.map{ |k,v| k if (v==1) }.compact # => [4, 1]
```

It replaces the `select{...}.keys` with `map{...}.compact` so it's not really an improvement, and, to me is a bit harder to understand.