# How to remove objects that have duplicates in an array

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove from the array elements that are repeated. in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444269/remove-from-the-array-elements-that-are-repeated-in-ruby)

I would like to do this:

```
my_array = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
my_array_without_duplicates = [3]
```

calling `my_array.uniq` will give me `[1, 2, 3]`, which is not the result I want. Is there an efficient way of doing this? What I am doing right now is too ugly to post.

Comment: this isn't valid ruby syntax - do you mean `[]`, not `{}`?

Comment: Yes I've changed to []. Speed typing FTL.

Comment: do you required the original order to be preserved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_array.group_by{|e| e}.select{|k,v| v.count == 1}.keys
```

or

```
my_array.select{|e| my_array.count(e) == 1}
```

BTW, you probably meant `my_array = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]` (with brackets, not braces).

Comment: +1 for the second option (first one isn't as clean).

Comment: @Peter: I have a feeling that the first would perform better in most cases, but yes, the latter is cleaner.

Comment: Isn't the second O(n^2)?

Comment: @tokland: yes, as soon as performance was an issue you would want to reconsider. But until then, I like the elegance of the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd get first the histogram of the input (see [Enumerable#frequency](http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/doc/api/core/Enumerable.html) or write your own) and then do the select:

```
require 'facets'
xs = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
fs = xs.frequency # {1=>2, 2=>2, 3=>1}
ys = xs.select { |x| fs[x] == 1 } # [3]
```

Ruby 1.9 keeps order in hashes, so this would probably suffice:

```
xs.frequency.select { |x, count| count == 1 }.keys # [3]
```

Which can be written in one step if you use the `Enumerable#map_select` abstraction (and assuming you have no `nil`s in the input), like this:

```
xs.frequency.map_select { |x, count| x if count == 1 } # [3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has well balance of simplicity and efficiency. Just that it looks long because the variable names are long.

```
my_array_without_duplicate = my_array.dup
my_array_without_duplicate.each_with_index {|e, i|
    my_array_without_duplicate.delete(e) if my_array_without_dupliate.index(e, i+1)}
```