# Comparing strings of equal lengths and noting where the differences occur

Tags: ruby, algorithm, string

Given two strings of equal length such that

```
s1 = "ACCT"
s2 = "ATCT"
```

I would like to find out the positions where there strings differ. So i have done this. (please suggest a better way of doing it. I bet there should be)

```
z= seq1.chars.zip(seq2.chars).each_with_index.map{|(s1,s2),index| index+1 if s1!=s2}.compact
```

z is an array of positions where the two strings are different. In this case z returns 2

Imagine that I add a new string

```
s3 = "AGCT"
```

and I wish to compare it with the the others and see where the 3 strings differ. We could do the same approach as above but this time

```
s1.chars.zip(s2.chars,s3.chars)
```

returns an array of arrays. Given two strings I was relaying on just comparing two chars for equality, but as I add more strings it starts to become overwhelming and as the strings become longer.

```
#=> [["A", "A", "A"], ["C", "T", "G"], ["C", "C", "C"], ["T", "T", "T"]]
```

Running

```
s1.chars.zip(s2.chars,s3.chars).each_with_index.map{|item| item.uniq}

 #=> [["A"], ["C", "T", "G"], ["C"], ["T"]]
```

can help reduce redundancy and return positions that are exactly the same(non empty subarray of size 1). I could then print out the indices and contents of the subarrays that are of size > 1.

```
s1.chars.zip(s2.chars,s3.chars,s4.chars).each_with_index.map{|item| item.uniq}.each_with_index.map{|a,index| [index+1,a] unless a.size== 1}.compact.map{|h| Hash[*h]}
#=> [{2=>["C", "T", "G"]}]
```

I feel that this will glide to a halt or get slow as I increase the number of strings and as the string lengths get longer. What are some alternative ways of optimally doing this?
Thank you.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the generic diff algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Algorithm

Comment: possible duplicate of [diff a ruby string or array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80091/diff-a-ruby-string-or-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's where I'd start. I'm purposely using different strings to make it easier to see the differences:

```
str1 = 'jackdaws love my giant sphinx of quartz'
str2 = 'jackdaws l0ve my gi4nt sphinx 0f qu4rtz'
```

To get the first string's characters:

```
str1.chars.with_index.to_a - str2.chars.with_index.to_a
=> [["o", 10], ["a", 19], ["o", 30], ["a", 35]]
```

To get the second string's characters:

```
str2.chars.with_index.to_a - str1.chars.with_index.to_a
=> [["0", 10], ["4", 19], ["0", 30], ["4", 35]]
```

There will be a little slow down as the strings get bigger, but it won't be bad.

---

EDIT: Added more info.

If you have an arbitrary number of strings, and need to compare them all, use `Array#combination`:

```
str1 = 'ACCT'
str2 = 'ATCT'
str3 = 'AGCT'

require 'pp'

pp [str1, str2, str3].combination(2).to_a
>> [["ACCT", "ATCT"], ["ACCT", "AGCT"], ["ATCT", "AGCT"]]
```

In the above output you can see that `combination` cycles through the array, returning the various `n` sized combinations of the array elements.

```
pp [str1, str2, str3].combination(2).map{ |a,b| a.chars.with_index.to_a - b.chars.with_index.to_a }
>> [[["C", 1]], [["C", 1]], [["T", 1]]]
```

Using combination's output you could cycle through the array, comparing all the elements against each other. So, in the above returned array, in the "ACCT" and "ATCT" pair, 'C' was the difference between the two, located at position 1 in the string. Similarly, in "ACCT" and "AGCT" the difference is "C" again, in position 1. Finally for 'ATCT' and 'AGCT' it's 'T' at position 1.

Because we already saw in the longer string samples that the code will return multiple changed characters, this should get you pretty close.

Comment: would you suggest then doing a pairwise comparison when given more than 2 strings? Assume you have 3 or four strings.

Comment: Thanks! pretty close. I appreciate!

Comment: In `ruby 2.1.x` use there's no `with_index` method. You can use `each_with_index` method to accomplish the same.

Comment: @atmosx: Since when isn't there a `with_index` method in 2.1+? In 2.1.4 `with_index` exists in http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index. How do you think `each_with_index` is implemented?

Comment: @theTinMan: Hm, you're right. Yesterday I needed to implement something similar so I used the above code `with_index` came up as `unknown method` while `each_with_index` worked fine, so I figured I should share the info, but now I'm not sure why this happened. I'm using ruby-2.1.2p195 (rvm).

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

```
strings = %w[ACCT ATCT AGCT]
```

First, join the strings, and make a hash of all the positions for each character.

```
joined = strings.join
positions = (0...joined.length).group_by{|i| joined[i]}
# => {"A"=>[0, 4, 8], "C"=>[1, 2, 6, 10], "T"=>[3, 5, 7, 11], "G"=>[9]}
```

Then, group the indices by their corresponding position within each string, remove those that are repeated as many times as the number of strings. This part is a variant of [an algorithm that Jorg suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444269/remove-from-the-array-elements-that-are-repeated).

```
length = strings.first.length
n = strings.length
diff = Hash[*positions.map{|k, v| 
  [k, v.group_by{|i| i % length}.reject{|i, is| is.length == n}.keys]
}]
```

This will give something like:

```
diff
# => {"A"=>[], "C"=>[1], "T"=>[1], "G"=>[1]}
```

which means that, "A" appears in the same positions in all strings, and "C", "T", and "G" differ at position 1 (count starts from 0) of the strings.

If you simply want to know the positions where the strings differ, do

```
diff["G"] + diff["A"] + diff["C"] + diff["T"]
# or diff["G"] + diff["A"] + diff["C"]
# => [1]
```

**Solution 2**

Note that, by maintaining an array of indices where a pairwise comparison fails, and keep adding to indices to it, comparison of `s1` against the rest (`s2`, `s3`, ...) will suffice.

```
length = s1.length
diff = []
[s2, s3, ...].each{|s| diff += (0...length).reject{|i| s1[i] == s[i]}}
```

*Explanation in a bit more detail*

Suppose

```
s1 = 'GGGGGGGGG'
s2 = 'GGGCGGCGG'
s3 = 'GGGAGGCGG'
```

After`s1` and `s2` are compared, we have the set of indices `[3, 6]` that represents where they differ. Now, when we add `s3` into consideration, it does not matter whether we compare it with `s1` or with `s2` because, if `s1[i]` and `s2[i]` are different, then `i` is already included in the set `[3, 6]`, so it does not make difference whether or not either of them are different from `s3[i]` and `i` is to be added to the set. On the other hand, if `s1[i]` and `s2[i]` are the same, it also does not make difference which one of them we compare with `s3[i]`. Therefore, pairwise comparison of `s1` with `s2`, `s3`, ... is enough.

Answer (score -1):

You almost certainly don't want to be doing this analysis with your own code. Rather, you want to be handing it off to an existing [multiple sequence alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_sequence_alignment) tool, like [Clustal](http://www.clustal.org/).

I realise this is not an answer to your question, but i hope it's a solution to your problem!

Comment: Sorry this might not be the answer to my  question. For one, multiple alignment assume some substitution function and a gap penalty and assume an evolutionary history.this would be wrong in cases where the strings have no such relationships and i wish not to make substitution assummations. :)

Comment: You could always use a substitution matrix that weighted all substitutions equally. You would still have a gap penalty; if you wanted to not use gaps, you could make it incredibly large, so no gap would ever be opened.